# MYSQL is consuming 100% of CPU usage

Tags: mysql, central-processing-unit, usage

Been monitoring `WHM > Process Manager` for a while now, and a particular process from MYSQL keep eating up CPU Usage playing from 30%-100% from time to time

```
PID : 3618
owner : mysql
CPU% : 100.60
Memory : 17.01

/usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --log-error=xxx.xxxxxxxxxx.com.err --open-files-limit=50000 --pid-file=xxx.xxxxxxxxxx.com.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Anyone experience the same issue and can share solution please?

Comment: So you're application does stuff. Is that a problem?

Comment: Also 100% cpu usage is fairly confusing because it doesn’t mean it’s maxing out the CPU. It means 100% of one core. So if you have a 4 core machine 400% would be maxing out the full CPU. So it’s a much better situation than it appears

Answer (score 0):

You should check the active queries to see which application/db/query take most of the CPU load.

- Login into root of MySQL
- Run the query: SHOW PROCESSLIST;

From result, you can see running queries, with DB it access, how long it runned, the query itself.

You may need knowledge of database to check performance and tuning up the query.